# libVLC does not play progressive mp4 from http source on Android

Tags: android, http, mp4, libvlc, progressive

i try to play mp4 video from http source with libvlc. when moov atom placed after mdat, libVLC prints error:

```
E/VLC: [00000055a5bea948/4a6b] mp4 stream: no moov before mdat and the stream is not seekable
```

but stream plays.

If i put moov atom before mdat, it does not print any warnings but does not play either.
If i try to play both files from local storage - everything works fine - both files plays well.

Standalone VLC android player has the same behavior.
Desktop version of VLC(linux) plays both files and both ways - HTTP and local files.

Has anybody ever faced this issue?